# Formally and Informally describe the language of this grammar

Tags: theory, proof, automata, formal-languages

I have a question I would like some help with:

Formally and informally describe the language of the following grammar `G = (Σ, N, S, P)`:

```
Σ = {a,b,c}
N = {S,T,X}
S = S
P = {
  S->aTXc,
  S->bTc,
  T->aTX,
  T->bT,
  TXX->T,
  Tc->empty string,
  TXc-a>
}
```

Moreover, briefly and informally explain how this grammar generates its language.

Hint: Use `|w|x` notation to describe the language of this grammar.

Comment: Again one of these "Do my homework" posts... Did you try something?

Comment: I have this same problem. We have been attempting to work this out for the past 24 hours amongst other questions. We came up with this generating any amount and sequence of a s and b s but I can't tell if there are limitations or how to describe it. @uwe

Comment: What does `TXc-a>` mean?  Is it a typo for `TXc->a`? a typo for `TXca->` ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the language of the grammar

```
S   → bTc | aTXc
T   → bT | aTX
TXX → T
Tc  → λ
TXc → a
```

is `(a|b)+`. First, consider derivations from `T` using the `T`-productions:

```
T ⇒* bnT   (T → bT)
T ⇒* anTXn (T → aTX)
```

where `n > 0`. Since `T → bT` and `T → aTX` can be applied in arbitrary order, it follows that

```
T ⇒* uTX|u|a
```

where `u` has the form `(a|b)+` and `|u|a ≥ 0`. Next, consider the production `TXX → T`:

```
T ⇒* uTX|u|a ⇒* uTX1(|u|a (mod 2) ≡ 1)
```

where `1(P) = 1` if `P` and `0` otherwise. Putting this together with the `S`-productions, we have:

```
S ⇒ bTc ⇒* buTX1(|u|a (mod 2) ≡ 1)c ⇒ buTc ⇒ bu
S ⇒ aTXc ⇒* auTX1(|u|a (mod 2) ≡ 1)Xc ⇒ auTXc ⇒ aua
```

if `|u|a (mod 2) ≡ 0` and

```
S ⇒ bTc ⇒* buTX1(|u|a (mod 2) ≡ 1)c ⇒ buTXc ⇒ bua
S ⇒ aTXc ⇒* auTX1(|u|a (mod 2) ≡ 1)Xc ⇒ auTXXc ⇒ auTc ⇒ au
```

if `|u|a (mod 2) ≡ 1` where `u` has the form `(a|b)+`. In the last step of the preceding derivations, applying more `T`-productions does not generate strings having a different form. Thus, I believe that all derivable strings have the form `(a|b)+`. My concern is that you were instructed to use `|u|a` notation to describe the grammar's language, so this belief might be in error.